# Replacing links in the content with processed links in rails using nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink, nokogiri

The feature I am currently working on is to replace all the links in the content with processed links. For that I am iterating all the links using Nokogiri(https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri). The code is below

```
def replace_links(content)

  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(content)
  doc.css("a[href]").each do |link|
    link["href"] =(url_for(
                     controller: "some_controller",
                     action: "some_action",
                     signature: generate_signature))
  end

 content.sub!(content, doc.css('body').inner_html)

end
```

This works great when I don't have `<p>` tag in the content(Please look at the image I added below). The Nokogiri wraps the content with

tag, If content itself has a page means, The processed content will have unexpected **p tag ** in it. How do I can proceed in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an HTML fragment.

Try this

```
def replace_links(content) 
  fragment = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(content)
  doc.css("a[href]").each do |link| 
    link['href'] = ... 
  end
  return fragment.to_html
end
```

And no need for that `sub!` hack, just return `fragment.to_html`.